# How do I figure out why people aren't getting my emails from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I use Gmail for all my email, and most of the domains I own are verified by Google and I can send mail through them (using smtp.google.com).  This mostly seems to work, but there are a few people who *never* get emails I send using one of my alternate accounts.

I've followed [all the instructions on Google's Help Pages](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15953), and they're weren't helpful: yes, I was sending to the correct address, and the emails show up in Sent Mail, and I don't get bounce notifications, and the recipients don't get my emails in their Spam folders.  The emails just don't arrive.  Sending an email from one of my *other* addresses works, which implies to me it's something to do with the specific email address I'm sending from.

How can I figure out what the problem is, and fix it?

Comment: Do you have an SPF record that says that google's servers are authorized to send mail on behalf of your domain?

Comment: It's the first I've heard of it.  So, no.  I've got 1and1 handling my DNS entries; I expect there's no way to set it up on their servers?  What do I need to do to get it to work?

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/859/how-can-i-create-an-spf-record-on-my-1and1-com-hosted-domain

Comment: seems like @mark4o already answered your question... too bad it was not given as an answer, huh?

Comment: There are mail servers that reject mail if you don't have an SPF record??

Answer (score 4):

Your domain needs a Sender Policy Framework - see [SPF record](http://www.openspf.org/SPF_Record_Syntax).

Though it is not a standard, it is highly recommended as an [anti-SPAM measure](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework).

It is optional but some stupid mail servers reject mail if this record is not present.

[Here is Google Support on how to set it.](https://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?answer=178723)