# Only Gmail treats mails from my domain as spam

Tags: gmail, domain

Gmail is putting emails from my domain in junk, I've followed this question and verified all the steps but still facing the same issue: [Gmail treats mails from my domain as spam. Why? How to avoid it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9157/gmail-treats-mails-from-my-domain-as-spam-why-how-to-avoid-it)

I've tested PTR record, SPF record and DKIM record everything is fine, still only Gmail puts emails from my domain in junk.

It's working fine on Hotmail and Yahoo!.

Answer (score 3):

Apart from all the steps that were mentioned in that answer, you have to take care of another thing.
Email providers like "Gmail" use "Spamhaus" to gather information about malicious websites and domains.

You need to make sure your domain name is not listed on Spamhaus. If your domain is listed, all emails originating from your domain will always go to spam box.

Comment: No It's not listed there, just check

Answer (score 0):

While SPF and DKIM are important first steps, I would recommend you now implement DMARC. 
- A checklist on how to deploy DMARC can be found [here](https://space.dmarcian.com/dmarc-deployment-checklist/). 
- Additional articles and videos describing DMARC can be found [here](https://space.dmarcian.com/toc/).

The TL;DR is 
- SPF & DKIM provide basics ways of allowing a receiving mail system of knowing if the sending server is approved to send on your domain's behave but have some shortcomings. DMARC takes this a step further with more stringent and useful tests.

Lastly, make sure you aren't actually sending spam. United States law lays out some guidelines including providing an unsubscribe link along with acceptable sending behaviors. Google the wikipedia article on 'Canned Spam Act' for more info.