# Only Gmail treats mails from my domain as spam

Tags: gmail, domain

Gmail is putting emails from my domain in junk.

I've followed [Gmail treats mails from my domain as spam. Why? How to avoid it?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9157/gmail-treats-mails-from-my-domain-as-spam-why-how-to-avoid-it) and verified all the steps but am still facing the same issue. I've tested PTR record, SPF record and DKIM record everything is fine, still only Gmail puts emails from my domain in junk.

It's working fine on Hotmail and Yahoo.

Comment: This would seem to be more appropriate for [webmasters.se].

Answer (score 2):

If it's a configuration issue, this [Mail Tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) will point it out. If it's not a configuration issue and you follow their [Guidelines](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/81126) then it's either a content issue with Google or they got your IP and/or DOMAIN flagged in their system and they only way to get out of it will be to have users constantly click the "Not Spam" on your messages and add your email to their contact list.

Answer (score 2):

- First step: Make sure you aren't sending actual spam. I recommend reviewing this wiki article on the USA's "[CAN-SPAM Act of 2003](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003)". Even if you aren't in the US, Google is and must abide by US law.
- PTR and reverse DNS lookups are outdated and I highly doubt Google uses them. These applied when a company used one server to send and receive mail. In the current environment of cloud mail services, it's not practical to have the same IPs sending and receiving mail. As a real world example, every single message sent by Google Apps or Gmail fails reverse DNS because the IPs Google uses to send mail are not the same IPs Google uses to receive mail.
- SPF, DKIM, and DMARC are the current standards to  let recipients of your messages know your messages are legitimately from you and not phishing or spam attacks with spoofed header information.
- I highly recommend using the [DMARC Deployment Checklist](https://space.dmarcian.com/dmarc-deployment-checklist/) as a roadmap to ensure you have SPF, DKIM, and DMARC correctly configured. This is not a short process, but in the end it will help more of your messages be correctly delivered while also protecting your domain from email based attacks.
- In the end, the recipient's inbox is under their control, and possibly that of their company's IT department. If they have rules, or settings in place that put your messages into their spam label, you would have to reach out to their IT department and ask them to make a change on their end.